# How to Reach Bottom Sheet from another activity?

Tags: java, android

I tried to use a bottom sheet which use a layout of an activity, not dialog.

[Here is my bottom sheet][1]

But I can't access "Pay Now" button. I tried to use click listener in the same activity, but nothing happens. How can I listen this button and where?

**Activity of Bottom Sheet**

```
public class SheetActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button sheet_button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sheet);

    sheet_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sheet_button);
    //

    sheet_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            sheet_button.setText("deneme");
        }
    });
}}
```

Comment: post code how you inflate it then we can help you attach a listener

Comment: I posted java file of bottom sheet. I tried to submit XML but I had problem, no idea why. Its just the layout of screenshot. I "include" this layout to MainActivity layout. Thats all I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generally pretty simple.

If your bottom sheet is a DialogFragment or BottomSheetDialogFrament attach a listener into the `onAttach(Context context)` method like so:

define the interface in the Fragment:

```
interface CheckoutButtonListener {
    void onClick(/*provide whatever arguments you need to back to parent*/);
}
```

usage:

```
// Define the member variable
private CheckoutButtonListener mCheckoutListener;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context){
    super.onAttach(context);
    try{
        mCheckoutListener = (CheckoutButtonListener) context;
    }catch(ClassCastException){
      // Handle the error silently or rethrow so usage is expected
    }
}
```

Then when you attach the listener to the button:

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        mCheckoutListener.onClick(); // call the interface method
    }
});
```

Finally, implement the interface in whatever Activity is showing the sheet:

```
class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CheckoutButtonListener {

     //.. other code

     // interface method
     @Override
     public void onClick(){
        // do whatever you need to do
     }
}
```

If you are not using a re-usable bottom sheet (i.e as a DialogFragment) then you should include this code in each place you display it, however better to modularize.

Good Luck and Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can I use dynamically a layout of an activity as dialog? I tried and did. That layout has SQLite variables, but once I changed SQLite variables, that layout doesn't show. In this case, what kind of process I should go with?

Comment: You will have to explain a bit more. What do you mean by changed the variables and now the view doesn't show?

Comment: There are 4-5 activies like about food, coffee, vegatable etc... When user click the "+" button, I add that product to SQLite as shopping cart. And I show the items of shopping cart in bottom sheet as collapsed. In expanded mode, user can see which items there are in the basket. In this case, I called SQLite in SheetActivity.java then I used its layout as bottom sheet. When I click + for item, it adds to SQLite but doesn't show in the layout.

Comment: There is a good chance then that you are not updating your dataset in memory after the database file gets updated. Create a new question and ask the community but include a code example and then paste the link to it here.

Comment: @kandroidj I have a related question. What if I want to send some data back to the bottomsheet after I fetch data in the activity? Example: button click on fragment requires data from API. Using the above interface example, I get the activity to get the data, but then how do I pass that data to the fragment?